# continued fractions estimate

Tags: continued-fractions

I am trying to do some estimates concerning continued fractions and according to my teacher I should get

$\left\lvert \alpha - \frac{p_n}{q_n}\right\lvert > \frac{1}{q_n+q_{n+1}} > \frac{1}{2q_{n+1}}$.

where $\frac{p_n}{q_n} = [a_0,a_1,...,a_n]$ is the continued fraction

The second inequality is clear, but I don't understand where I can derive the first one from. Thanks for any explanation.

I need this to prove the following: if $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{a_n+1}{q_n^\sigma} < \infty$

then there exists $\gamma$ such that for all $(p, q) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}^* \left\lvert \alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right\lvert \geq \frac{\gamma}{2^{2+\sigma}}$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See chapter 1, theorem 9 of [khinchin - continued fractions](http://bit.ly/pdf-khinchin).

Comment: Or the last one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems), stronger than your first inequality. Regarding your context, see [this link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) for further references (and again, compare to the above).